# Java Script external file linking to html

Tags: javascript, html

I have a problem with using an external *.js file in a *.html file. 
What I want to achieve is to modify a div. No matter what I do I can't seem to make it working. Why isn't this working ?

```js
document.getElementById("MyDiv").color = "red";
x.color = "blue";
MyDiv.color = "red";
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
    <script src="JavaScript.js"></script>
    <title>js</title>
</head>
<body>
<div id="MyDiv">12</div>
</body>
</html>
```

[image],

Comment: x and MyDiv are undefined in your javascript.  a

Comment: I know, but even if I try to use document.getElementById("MyDiv").color = "red"; it is not working

Comment: document.getElementById("MyDiv").style.color = "red";  Your missing `style`

Answer (score 1):

Try

```
document.getElementById("MyDiv").style.color = "red";
```

after the document loaded. Usage of jQuery would be helpful. With jQuery:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
   document.getElementById("MyDiv").style.color = "red";
}
```

Or native: Put the script tag at the end of your body tag:

```
    <script>
      (function() {
          document.getElementById("MyDiv").style.color = "red";

      })();
    </script>
```

Comment: It is not working. Are there any additional steps that I have to make in order to communicate those files to each other ?

Comment: My bad. Look at the edited post. I hope it helps!

Answer (score 0):

Why cant you just include the Script in the `<head>`? If it is only that small piece then it should be no Problem. 
If you are linking to an external file, be sure the link path is correct.

Comment: The path is linked correctly I think, tried a physical pach "c:..." and the one that Visual studio gives, no results

Answer (score 0):

Code below will resolve your problem:

```js
var MyDiv = document.getElementById("MyDiv");
MyDiv.style.color = "red";
MyDiv.innerHTML = "asdkjnasd";
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
    <title>js</title>
</head>
<body>
<div id="MyDiv">12</div>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Seems to be working here.. but it doesn't work on my machine.

Comment: Remove that line: 
x.innerHTML.color = "blue";